# LLVM: Check if physical register is live

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

How can I find out whether at a given time a physical CPU register contains a "used" value, ie if it is live? I am using LLVM 3.4 C++ API.

Comment: 90% of what you might be doing with LLVM happens before physical registers even enter the picture. Are you really writing a post-RA machine code pass?

Comment: I don't want to write a pass (EDIT: unless I have to). I use a program compiled by llvm in multiple instances and I want to compare the state of the instances including the stack and physical registers.

Comment: You could analyze the machine code to see if the register will be read before the next instruction writing to it. Unfortunately I don't know how to make LLVM help you with that.

Comment: I was hoping that LiveVariables function pass could help me. But I could not add it to my Function Pass Manager because of other passes not being initialized...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you cannot. Long answer: LLVM IR represents some virtual machine with infinite number of typed registers. There is no information how everything will be turned into physical registers before the codegeneration.

Register liveness information is available inside backend after register allocation was performed.